# Asynchronous pushing of values to an array in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having an issue with pushing data to an array in the correct order that I'm fetching them using Vue's built in `$http.get()`:

I have `this.contacts` defined in the data object, and I have the following two methods, one that fetches some data to determine which contact/(s) to fetch, and another which fetches those contacts. The initial fetch is as follows:

```
this.$http.get(this.baseUrl + '/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=' + menuChildSlug).then(async response => {
  this.page = response.data[0]
  this.pageSections = this.page.acf.sections
  this.contactSections = this.page.acf.contacts
  for (let contact of this.contactSections) {
    let result = await this.fetchContactPostById(contact.add_contact.ID)
  }
}).catch(e => {
  this.errors.push(e)
})
```

The method that this fetch relies on is as follows:

```
fetchContactPostById: async function (postId) {
  this.$http.get(this.baseUrl + '/wp-json/acf/v3/contacts-api/' + postId).then(async response => {
    response.data.acf.id = postId
    let result = await this.contacts.push(response.data)
    return result
  }).catch(e => {
    this.errors.push(e)
  })
},
```

I feel that my `async`/`await` syntax has becoming muddled with my arrow functions `=>` but it seems that although the returned response is occurring as intended, the `push` itself isn't occurring as intended...any pro-tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `he method that this fetch relies on is as follows` - that method returns a promise that will immediately and always resolve to `undefined` - because you have no return value from that function

Comment: `await this.contacts.push(response.data)` makes no sense, since .push is syncrhonous

Comment: in fact, you dont' need `async/await` in `fetchContactPostById` at all ... just `return this.$http.get ...` and remove all occurrences of `async` and `await` keywords within that code

Comment: `it seems that although the returned response is occurring as intended` - no, `result` will be `undefined` in `let result = await this.fetchContactPostById(contact.add_contact.ID)`

Comment: @JaromandaX Awesome - worked like a charm. I think it's clear I fundamentally don't yet understand when to use `async` / `await`. Not that you need to points :D please add this as an answer to this issue and I'd gladly accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually do not need `async/await` at all in `fetchContactPostById` since there's only one asynchronous method used, and it returns a Promise

What you need to do is `return this.$http.get(....` and then remove all the async and await keywords

```
fetchContactPostById: function (postId) {
    return this.$http.get(this.baseUrl + '/wp-json/acf/v3/contacts-api/' + postId)
    .then(response => {
        response.data.acf.id = postId;
        let result = this.contacts.push(response.data);
        return result;
    }).catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e);
    })
},
```

as an aside - the `return result` - do you understand it returns a number (the new length of the array) and the calling code assigns this value but never actually uses it?

the streamlined code would be

```
this.$http.get(this.baseUrl + '/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=' + menuChildSlug).then(async response => {
      this.page = response.data[0];
      this.pageSections = this.page.acf.sections;
      this.contactSections = this.page.acf.contacts;
      for (let contact of this.contactSections) {
        await this.fetchContactPostById(contact.add_contact.ID);
      }
}).catch(e => {
    this.errors.push(e)
})
```

and

```
fetchContactPostById: function (postId) {
    return this.$http.get(this.baseUrl + '/wp-json/acf/v3/contacts-api/' + postId)
    .then(response => {
        response.data.acf.id = postId;
        this.contacts.push(response.data);
    }).catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e);
    })
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You call your data in a certain order, but the response will eventually be received in a different order.
(Depending on how your server will respond, thats' why the call is asynchronous).
If you want to keep the same order in your second array, you have to send the index of the first array to your second one.